# How to get all parameters of an east opening hyperbola given some points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a symmetric east opening hyperbola. I am only interested in the positive parts and I know the vertex point (*a*,0). I also know some random point on the curve. I thought this is enough to get all the parameters of

$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1
$$

but what I get is completely different and even seems to be a north opening hyperbola (if it is a hyperbola at all).

I have for y:
$$
y = \frac{b\sqrt{(x+a)(x-a)}}{a}
$$

for x:
$$
x = \frac{a\sqrt{y^2 + b^2}}{b}
$$

and for b:
$$
b = - \frac{ay\sqrt{(a+x)(-a+x)}}{(a+x)(a-x)}
$$

Since the *y* part of the vertex point is *0*, I use a different point on the curve to calculate *b*. But somewhere must still be a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know $a$ and since you know some random point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the hyperbola, you can write 
$$\frac{x_0^2}{a^2} - \frac{y_0^2}{b^2} = 1$$
where $b$ is the unknown. 
This gives
$$b^2 = \frac{y_0^2a^2}{x_0^2-a^2}$$
hence
$$b = \frac{|y_0|a}{\sqrt{x_0^2-a^2}}.$$

Comment: Hmm but $a$ is a rather small number while $x$ is a rather big number so I will always end up with a negative in the root

Comment: You're right, there was a mistake ; I wrote + instead of - in the equation of the hyperbola. It's corrected.